# Incomplete page data using RSelenium

Tags: r, windows, selenium, screen-scraping, rselenium

I am trying to download a page similar to [this one](https://www.cleartrip.com/hotels/details/hotel-royal-paradise-709260?c=290921%7C021021&r=2,0&compId=&fr=undefined&ur=7&urt=featured&stp=none&pahCCRequired=true&op=true&area=&sd=1631919589220&lowRate=true&dest_code=35485&tags=#location) (showing the map) using `RSelenium`.

The page loads fine using a standalone browser.  However, when I attempt to load it using `RSelenium`, Selenium opens the browser, but the page appears blank, and the page source appears incomplete.  This is true across browsers, computers, and scraping tools.

I assume I need to post additional data with the request. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.  Code examples below.

Edit: To @Nad's suggestion, I don't see a way to click "Larger Map" as this isn't loading - that would be a perfect solution, though!  @Earl, I arrived at this after scraping the "search url" links (see link below).

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(httr)
library(xml2)
library(RSelenium)
library(stringr)
library(tidyverse)

 ### URLs to try

search_url <- "https://www.cleartrip.com/hotels/results?city=New+Delhi&state=Delhi&country=IN&area=&poi=&hotelId=&hotelName=&SearchTag=&dest_code=35485&chk_in=07/10/2021&chk_out=11/10/2021&adults1=2&children1=0&num_rooms=1"

hotel_url <-"https://www.cleartrip.com/hotels/details/hotel-royal-paradise-709260?c=290921%7C021021&r=2,0&compId=&fr=undefined&ur=7&urt=featured&stp=none&pahCCRequired=true&op=true&area=&sd=1631919589220&lowRate=true&dest_code=35485&tags=#location"

## Selenium code
### initialize

rD <- rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=4545L, verbose =F) 
remDr <- rD[["client"]]

remDr$navigate(search_url) ## Works fine
remDr$navigate(hotel_url) ## Fails - loads blank page

### kill processes (for wrapup/closeout)

remDr$close()
pDrv$stop()
rD$server$stop()
remDr$server$stop()
pDrv$server$stop()
gc()
system("taskkill /im java.exe /f", intern=FALSE, ignore.stdout=FALSE)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why not click on [Larger map](https://www.google.com/maps?ll=28.5969,77.344&z=15&t=m&hl=en-US&gl=US&mapclient=embed&q=28%C2%B035%2748.8%22N+77%C2%B020%2738.4%22E+28.596900,+77.344000@28.5969,77.344)  and get screenshot of that page?

Comment: How did you arrive in this page?

Comment: Look at https://www.cleartrip.com/robots.txt web scraping is not allowed for the website.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to load the page with

```
library(RDCOMClient)

hotel_url <- "https://www.cleartrip.com/hotels/details/hotel-royal-paradise-709260?c=290921%7C021021&r=2,0&compId=&fr=undefined&ur=7&urt=featured&stp=none&pahCCRequired=true&op=true&area=&sd=1631919589220&lowRate=true&dest_code=35485&tags=#location"
IEApp <- COMCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
IEApp[['Visible']] <- TRUE
IEApp$Navigate(hotel_url)
```